# Debugging linked server that only runs short period of time on SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2014

On an SQL Server 2008 (latest version) I have a linked server to an Excel file that works smooth, using following settings:

```
@srvproduct=N'ACE 12.0', @provider=N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' and @provstr=N'Excel 12.0; HDR=Yes'
```

Moreover, query and connect timeout are set to 30s.

The moment I generate the **exact** same linked server on SQL Server 2014  (latest version), the linked server works fine.

Unfortunately, after around a day, the connection from SQL Server 2014 to the Excel file stops working. For example, when right-clicking on the linked server and clicking on *Test Connection*,  SQL Server Management Studio freezes for around half an hour. The error I get is following:

---

The test connection to the linked server failed.

===================================

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

Program Location: 
at  Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection. ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType, Boolean retry)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.ExecuteNonQuery (String cmd, Boolean retry)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.LinkedServer.TestConnection()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer. LinkedServer-ConnectionTest.Invoke()

===================================

Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Error Number: -2
Severity: 11
State: 0

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType, Boolean retry)

===================================

The wait operation timed out

---

My only solution - so far - is to restart the "SQL Server" service. After having done this, also the linked server works again.

Is there e.g. a way to debug at what point the linked server stops working?

Comment: FYI: I have had bad experience with Excel drivers under SQL Server, in one instance even causing SQL Server service to suddenly abort. Could it be that something else opens your Excel file and therefore locks out SQL Server?

Comment: @Alex As far as I know, only the SQL server instance opens/looks into the Excel file.

Comment: If you have a static Excel I suggest that you load it to a table and then read from table. Another option I remember I needed to set was to run driver "inprocess" (more dangerous but more stable). I think it is called "Allow inprocess". I have always used `OPENROWSET` funtion as our files were read once into table.

Comment: Unfortunately, the purpose of having the Excel file is that users unfamiliar with SQL can update it.

Comment: RE "the purpose of having the Excel file is that users unfamiliar with SQL can update it": so your Excel file is opened by users while being used by SQL Server - BIG NO NO. To demonstate the problem: create Excel file and keep it open in Excel, then use data import wizard to read from it, it will fail.

Comment: You may try using `OPENROWSET` function to read it, as **I think** it will not hold connection to the file after your query finished executing. It was a long time ago since I had to solve these issues.

Comment: As a final comment: if you need a quick and dirty familiar front end for users you can try access (access can manipulate SQL Server tables directly) or you can add macros to Excel spreadsheet to push data changes to table.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into `OPENROWSET` as an alternative option. "so your Excel file is opened by users while being used by SQL Server [...]" - No it is never opened, only replaced by an updated version (though, this is very seldom and should not interfer with the described errors).

Comment: please update your question / add an answer if and when you solve it. Even if it is a workaround of some sort.

Comment: Yes, of course!